# Do you know why I get an error with this sample code?

Tags: pine-script-v5

Do you know why I get an error with this sample code?
Error : Syntax error at input '('

```
txt_example_1 = indi_example == 'Example 1'  and indi_example_2 == 'Example 2'  ? 'Text 1' : na
txt_example_2 = indi_example == 'Example 3'  and indi_example_2 == 'Example 4'  ? 'Text 2' : na
txt_example_3 = indi_example == 'Example 5'  and indi_example_2 == 'Example 6'  ? 'Text 3' : na
txt_example_4 = indi_example == 'Example 7'  and indi_example_2 == 'Example 8'  ? 'Text 4' : na
txt_example_5 = indi_example == 'Example 9'  and indi_example_2 == 'Example 10' ? 'Text 5' : na
txt_example_6 = indi_example == 'Example 11' and indi_example_2 == 'Example 12' ? 'Text 6' : na

var watermark = table.new(position.top_center, 1, 1)
if barstate.isfirst
    table.cell_set_text(watermark, 0, 0, text = txt_example_1 : txt_example_1 : txt_example_1 : txt_example_1 : txt_example_1 : txt_example_1 : na)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here

```
text = txt_example_1 : txt_example_1 : txt_example_1 : txt_example_1 : txt_example_1 : txt_example_1 : na)
```

The sequence of string : string : string : isn't a pine accepted syntax

If you want to concatenate strings, use the + character like this

```
text = text = txt_example_1 + txt_example_1 + txt_example_1 + txt_example_1 + txt_example_1 + txt_example_1)
```